# Typescript "-bash: tsc.cmd: command not found"

Tags: cmd, typescript, tsc

Learning typescript recently. So I npm installed typescript globally(version 1.8.10), and it's working well to compile ts file into js file. However, when I tried to tsc.cmd to watch the changes in the src file(command line: "tsc.cmd -watch"), it gave me the error message in the title description--"-bash: tsc.cmd: command not found".

Appreciate it if someone who had similar situations can give me a hint. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across that issue too.

Instead of running:

```
tsc.cmd -w
```

Run:

```
tsc -w
```

That's it! Hope that was helpful :D

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It was actually a spelling error, I changed it and it worked.